# Jekyll - Scss map has not a valid value

Tags: dictionary, sass

This scss map cause my `jekyll build` to fail (Jekyll 2.5.3):

```
$content_width: (
  mobile:    100%,
  tablet:    500px,
  desktop:   800px
);
```

I've got this error:

> Error: (mobile: 100%, tablet: 500px, desktop: 800px) isn't a valid CSS value.

AFAIK, it's a perfectly valid scss map, so why wouldn't Jekyll accept it?
I first thought mixing percents and pixel was the point, but I've got the same error with pixel only values.

Where it starts to driving me crazy is that I already have another map, which it accepted:

```
$sq-breakpoints: (
    mobile:    320px,
    tablet:    768px,
    desktop:   992px
) !default;
```

I can copy/paste the map, I'll get the error...

Any idea?

Comment: There's not enough code here to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oooookay...
My bad, stupid answer for a stupid question.

It's written **"valid CSS value"**, and not "valid SCSS value".

There was a hidden use of `$content_width` in my scss files:

```
img {
  max-width: $content_width;
}
```

This fail as soon as I changed the variable from a pixel value to a map. I need to use:

```
img {
  max-width: map-get($content_width, desktop);
}
```

Comment: In my case, there are two classes: Parent and Child; both of them were mapped to a common SCSS variable. That means, parent class was also mapped with the common variable and the child class was also mapped separately to that same variable. As soon as, I used the child-class inside the parent-class, compiler throws same error that ' it's not valid CSS value'. Then, I removed the mapping from both parent and child classes. Simply, I used SCSS variable without mapping. What I observed is that SCSS compiler does not compile re-occurrence call of  'map' function from a nested classes.